# Everything happens for a reason

Tags: grammatical-number

Why can't it be "all things happen for **reasons**" but "all things happen for **a reason**"?

Please help! I am stuck in here!

Comment: Well, for one thing because both of those sound yucky, compared to the original.

Comment: 'All things happen for a reason' looks illogical but is the idiomatic (agreed as acceptable and usually used) formulation. The 'reason' in 'for a reason' should not be regarded as a count noun in this idiom; 'all things happen for a reason' should just be seen as a paraphrase of 'there is nothing that happens without there being a causal factor'. Very close is 'there's no smoke without fire', where both nouns are obviously in the noncount usage.

Comment: There are two quantifiers there; a universal quantifier ("all")  for _things_ ()wjatever **that** means), and an existential ("a") for _reasons for things_. Logically it's `For every T there is at least one R` (formally ***`∀`t `∃`r ( r (t) )***. The separate quantifiers mean there's no necessary agreement, unless _r_ and _t_ are set up so that there's one and only one _r_ for every _t_; but we wouldn't say that this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you analyse the sentences logically, you come to the following interpretations:

1. Everything happens for a reason.  ----> Every individual thing happens for some reason.
2. "All things happen for reasons."  ----> All things happen for one or more reasons each.
3. "All things happen for a reason"  ---->  All (different) things happen for the same reason. (e.g. because God wills it.)

The first is the usual formulation and makes the most sense.

Note: If you read rapidly and without analysis, 1 and 3 will seem similar in meaning. Version 2 is sufficiently odd-looking that most people would stop to work out what it is supposed to mean.